# Linear project when X includes a constant

Tags: regression, projection

In [Hamilton's](https://books.google.com/books?id=B8_1UBmqVUoC&dq=time%20series%20analysis%20hamilton&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYsuv_0OPfAhXqY98KHTaaD2AQ6AEIKjAA) text I ran across the following statement: if $X$ includes a constant then the linear projection of $aY+b$ is $aP(Y\mid X)+b$ where $P(Y\mid X)$ is the linear projection of $y$ on $x$. I’m having trouble proving this. Specifically this implies that if $X$ has a constant then $E(X’)E(XX’)X=I$ which I don’t see.

Comment: In Hamilton text?

Comment: James Hamilton Times series analysis

Comment: Do you have a page number?

Comment: It’s the first section of chapter 4 discussing linear projection right before he talks about OLS estimate

Comment: It’s page 75 of Hamilton

Comment: There's nothing to prove: you are merely invoking the definition of "linear."

Comment: Linear projection has a specific definition: when plugging into that definition it doesn’t seem to work out as intended. Hence the last part of that question.